# jQuery replace text but don't strip out HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where I can replace text based on an ID.

This is set up and is working

```
$('#qs_policy .questionTitle').text("This text has been changed");
```

In the application there is a separate function which I am unable to change. This function adds a `<div>` called `<div class='tick--validation'></div>`

When I run the `.text()` method it strips out this `<div class='tick--validation'></div>` element.

How can I change the text but keep the `<div class='tick--validation'></div>` from disappearing?

Here is a JSFiddle of my example above - https://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/59z6gc4w/11/

Comment: Where is the div in the example?

Comment: Its dynamically generated so its not there by default

Comment: LOL, but it is there when you do the replacement.... We need to know what it is like so we can help....

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp element from the inner html, use that to replace the text, eg

```
var divTemp = $($('#qs_policy .questionTitle').html());
divTemp.text(newtext);
$('#qs_policy .questionTitle').html(divTemp.html());
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've updated my JSFiddle and I am getting a few Syntax errors - https://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/59z6gc4w/13/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, a function runs that appends a div into the div with a class of `questionTitle`. You want to change the textContent, but also want the div to appended correct?

***EDIT:*** *What if you wrap your text within the parent div into a p tag element. then target the p tag and change the text?*

- Run the function after the text method and the text will be changed however the div will also be appended.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $(".questionTitle").append("<div class='tick--validation'></div>"); 
  $('#qs_policy .questionTitle p').text("Text has been changed");
  // This represents a whole other function which we are unable to change or interact with
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="qs_policy">
    <div class="questionTitle">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Capture]

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I am unable to touch the tick-validation div element as it gets injected from another function. I was hoping there was a way to change the text and this div still gets injected after the text has been changed because currently when its changed the div doesnt get injected

Comment: What if you wrapped your text in a p tag within the parent `.questionTitle` class element? You could then target the p tag and change the text without having any effect on the functions insertion? If this is an option see my edit...